# AVFoundation and multiple view controllers

Tags: ios, avfoundation, tabbar

I'm leaning ios dev, and developing an audio player app. So I need to create an audio player controllable by any of the viewcontrollers of the app.

What I have done so far is to create a table view and play song of the clicked cell; also created the controls needed for an AVfoundation audio player,but all of that inside the same tab view controller.
Finally I had created a tab bar controller with the 5 table views i'll need for the list of audios to be played.

Can anyone help me to find the best way to control the player from all the viewcontrollers inside the tab bar?

Thanks

Above is my code from the View controller where the player is, this view controller has an table view and Player that works just fine.

```
@implementation ViewController {

    NSDictionary *Source01Details;
    NSArray *Source01Names;
    NSDictionary *Source02Details;
    NSArray *Source02Names;

    NSString *audioPath;
    NSURL *soundUrl;
    NSString *filename;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Source 01
    NSURL *url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"data_group_01" withExtension:@"plist"];
    Source01Details = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    Source01Names = Source01Details.allKeys;
    //Source 02
    NSURL *url2 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"data_group_02" withExtension:@"plist"];
    Source02Details = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfURL:url2];
    Source02Names = Source02Details.allKeys;

    //START AUDIO
    // Construct URL to sound file
    filename = @"audioteste.wav";
    audioPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],filename];
    soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];

    //Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];
    self.isPlaying = NO;
    [self.audioProgressBar setProgress:0];
    //END AUDIO
}

- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSTimer *)timer {
    if ([_audioPlayer currentTime]==0) {
        [self.audioProgressBar setProgress:([_audioPlayer currentTime]/[_audioPlayer duration])];
        [self.topPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLAY"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.isPlaying = NO;

        //[[self rowDisplay] setText:@"Trocar esta linha por update de checkbox!"];

    } else {
        [self.audioProgressBar setProgress:([_audioPlayer currentTime]/[_audioPlayer duration])];
    }
}

- (IBAction)playButton:(id)sender {
    //[_audioPlayer play];
    if (self.isPlaying) // Music is currently playing
    {   [_audioPlayer pause];
        [self.topPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLAY"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.isPlaying = NO;
    }
    else // Music is currenty paused/stopped
    {   [_audioPlayer play];
        [self.topPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PAUSE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        self.isPlaying = YES;}
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.23 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

- (IBAction)pauseButton:(id)sender {
    [_audioPlayer stop];
    _audioPlayer.currentTime = 0;
    self.isPlaying = NO;
    [self.topPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PLAY"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [[self sectionDisplay] setText:@""];
    [self.audioProgressBar setProgress:0];
    [[self rowDisplay] setText:@"Escolha uma dica para ouvir"];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView    {
    return 2;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0){
        return @"Base para Emagrecimento";
    } else {
        return @"Supermercado";
    }
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 0){
        return Source01Details.count;
    } else {
        return Source02Details.count;
    }
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //create cell
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    //Faz as células terem bordas redondas
    CALayer *cellimagelayer = cell.layer;
    [cellimagelayer setCornerRadius:9 ];
    [cellimagelayer setMasksToBounds:YES];

    //Insere uma imagem
    //UIImage *playImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"PLAY"];
    //[cell.imageView setImage:playImage];

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        cell.textLabel.text = Source01Names[indexPath.row] ;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = Source01Details[Source01Names[indexPath.row]] ;
    } else {
        cell.textLabel.text = Source02Names[indexPath.row] ;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = Source02Details[Source02Names[indexPath.row]] ;
    }
    //fill cell
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        filename = Source01Details[Source01Names[indexPath.row]] ;
        [[self sectionDisplay] setText: @"Base para Emagrecimento"];
        [[self rowDisplay] setText:Source01Names[indexPath.row]];
    } else {
        filename = Source02Details[Source02Names[indexPath.row]] ;
        [[self sectionDisplay] setText: @"Supermercado"];
        [[self rowDisplay] setText:Source02Names[indexPath.row]];
    }
    audioPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath],filename];
    soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:audioPath];

    // Create audio player object and initialize with URL to sound
    _audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundUrl error:nil];

    [_audioPlayer play];
    [self.topPlayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"PAUSE"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.isPlaying = YES;
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.23 target:self selector:@selector(updateProgressBar:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}
```

Comment: can you put some codes to show us where you're stuck so we can help you

Comment: is that helpful? I didnt write yet nothing in the 2º viewcontroller.